# Oracle 12c full text index maintainence

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, oracle12c, oracle-text

We are planning to use a context index for full text search in Oracle 12c standard edition.

The data on which search will run is a JSON containing one Channel post and its replies from a 3rd party tool that is loaded into our database.(basically, all the chats and replies(including other attributes like timestamp/user etc) are stored in this table).

We are expecting about 50k rows of data per year and a daily of 100-150 DMLs per day. Our index is "SYNC ON COMMIT" currently,so what are the recommendations for optimizing the Oracle Text index?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me preface my response with a disclaimer: I am exploring using Oracle Text as part of a POC currently, and my knowledge is somewhat limited as we're still in the research phase. Additionally, our datasets are in the 10s of millions with 100k DML operations daily.

From what I've read, Oracle Docs suggest scheduling both a FULL and REBUILD optimization for indexes which incur DML, so I currently have implemented the following in our dev environment.

```
execute ctx_ddl.optimize_index('channel_json_ctx_idx', 'FULL'); --run daily
execute ctx_ddl.optimize_index('channel_json_ctx_idx', 'REBUILD'); --run weekly
```

I cannot imagine with the dataset you've identified that your index will really become that fragmented and cause performance issues. You could probably get away with less frequent optimizations than what I've mentioned.

You could even forego scheduling the optimization and benchmark your performance. If you see it start to degrade, then note the timespan and perhaps count of DML operations for reference. Then run a 'FULL'. Then test performance. If performance improves, create a schedule. If performance does not improve, then run 'REBUILD'. Test performance. Assuming performance improves then you could schedule the 'REBUILD'for that time range and consider adding a more frequent 'FULL'.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Do you also know if there are some bugs or issues with  CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX that I need to be aware of? And does optimizing the index require any downtime?